# Angular translate with variable replacement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

i have followed this doc from angularjs:
https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/06_variable-replacement

I have this my module.config():

```
var translations = {
    HEADLINE: 'What an awesome module!',
    PARAGRAPH: 'Srsly!',
    PASSED_AS_TEXT: 'Hey there! I\'m passed as text value!',
    PASSED_AS_ATTRIBUTE: 'I\'m passed as attribute value, cool ha?',
    PASSED_AS_INTERPOLATION: 'Beginners! I\'m interpolated!',
    VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT: 'Hi, {{name}}'
  };

  $translateProvider
  .useLoader('$translatePartialLoader',{
    urlTemplate: url
  })
  .preferredLanguage('en')
  .translations('en', translations);

  $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitizeParameters');
```

The url is defined but i dont show it because its from a company.

So, in a template from a controller from a certain module (lets say 'home') which later on imports my main module i have this:

```
<p translate="VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT" translate-values="{ name: 'PascalPrecht' }"></p>
```

The output is nothing, it doesnt show anything, what am i doing wrong? I did it as the example.

Many thanks

Comment: Please, try to create a Minimal Complete and Verifiable example (at least a jsfilddle or any similar) in order to reproduce the issue. Is hard to help you with only the info you provided.

Comment: Updated the answer, i forgot to put the html in code format so it wasnt showing!

Comment: Well, the syntax is correct and it should work. That's why I was asking about a verifiable example in order to reproduce the issue with your very same code.

Comment: ikr, maybe it could be the angular-translate version?, im using angular-translate - v2.11.0 - 2016-05-18

Comment: Hard to tell, really. But I don't think so

Comment: I say it because i have download the html and script from the example in the link above, and it works perfectly fine. In that html it has other imports, anyway > 2.0 its supposed to be enough